# Almost sure convergence to $\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution, almost-everywhere

Let $X_1, Y_1, X_2, Y_2, \ldots$ be an i.i.d. sequence whose members have a uniform distribution on $[0,1]$ and let $f:[0,1] \to [0,1]$. Define $Z_i = \mathbb{1}_{\{ f(X_i) > Y_i \}}$.

I want to prove that 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\bigg[\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg)^2\bigg] \leq \frac{1}{4n}.
\end{align}

Therefore I first want to show that 
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \xrightarrow{\text{a.s.}} \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx.
\end{align}
In other words, we want to show that for all $\epsilon >0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\exists N: \forall n \geq N: \bigg|\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg| < \epsilon \bigg) = 1.
\end{align}
However, I can't come up with an expression for $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i$ using the fact that the $X_i,Y_i$'s are uniformly distributed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestion: Compute $E(Z_1)$ and apply Bienaymé-Chebychev inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note each $Z_i$ is iid $Bernoulli(p)$ where $p=P[f(X_1)>Y_1]=\int_0^1\int_0^{f(x)}1dydx=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

Hence $E(Z_i)=\int_0^1 f(x)dx$ for each $i$ so $E\left(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\right)=\int_0^1f(x)dx$.

Now note that $E\left[\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i-\int_0^1f(x)dx\right]^2=Var(\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Z_i)=\dfrac{Var(Z_1)}{n}\leq \dfrac{1}{4n}$ as if $A\sim Bernoulli(p)$ then $Var(A)=p(1-p)\leq \dfrac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks Landon Carter. I cannot link the above statement about $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i] = \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx$ with the definition of a.s. convergence in terms of $\mathbb{P}$ and $\epsilon$. Would you provide some details why this implies almost sure convergence?

Comment: \begin{align} &\mathbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx \bigg]^2\\ &= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \big(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\big)^2 - 2 \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\ \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx + \bigg(\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg)^2 \bigg]\\ 
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \big(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\big)^2\bigg] - 2 \mathbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i \bigg] \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx +  \bigg(\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg)^2 \\ 
&= \mathbb{E} \bigg[ \big(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\big)^2 \bigg] - 2\bigg(\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg)^2 + \bigg(\int_0^1 f(x)\ dx\bigg)^2 
\end{align}

Comment: Why is $\mathbb{E}\bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i - \int_0^1 f(x)\ dx \bigg]^2 = \text{Var}\bigg(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Z_i\bigg)$?

Comment: You do not have to use convergence at all.  Why will you use convergence? You are trying to prove an estimate, not the convergence. Anyway, note $E(Z-E(Z))^2=Var(Z)$ by definition.